# How to carry out fileupload in play(Scala)

Tags: scala, file-upload, playframework

I am trying to write a simple file upload application, that would upload a file to a server, but when I run the code, a get a type mismatch error. I got the code from the play framework documentation, click [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaFileUpload)  The error occurs around here:

```
picture.ref.moveTo(Paths.get(s"/tmp/picture/$filename"), replace = true)
```

The error around there says something like this:

```
Type mismatch, expected: File, actual: Path
```

My full code is below

```
def uploader = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
      val filename = Paths.get(picture.filename).getFileName
      picture.ref.moveTo(Paths.get(s"/tmp/picture/$filename"), replace = true)
      Ok("File uploaded")
    }.getOrElse {
      Redirect(routes.FileUploadController.index).flashing(
        "error" -> "Missing file")
    }
  }
```

Comment: The error is pretty simple to understand. It says that the method wanted a `File` but your have actually given it a `Path`. Just convert `Path` to `File` --
 `Paths.get(s"/tmp/picture/$filename").toFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 import java.io.File
 import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission._

 //If you need authenticating, simply use silhouette for ACL, otherwise replace this line
 def uploadPhoto = silhouette.SecuredAction.async(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    Future {
      request.body
        .file("photo")
        .map { photo =>

          val fileName = UUID.randomUUID.toString
          val pathToStorage = "default"
          val file = new File(s"$pathToStorage/$fileName.jpg")
          photo.ref.moveTo(file)
          val attr = util.EnumSet.of(OWNER_READ, OTHERS_READ, GROUP_READ)
          Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file.toPath, attr)
          Ok(s"$fileName.jpg")
        }
        .getOrElse {
          BadRequest("Missing file")
        }
    }
  }
```

If you want to simply upload a file from disk, just replace `file` variable to the next line:

```
val file = Paths.get(s"/path/to/picture.jpg").toFile
```

Also, it's a good practice to specify file parameters for `read/write/execute` modes, I've provided the example with permissions above.

Comment: Artem Rukavytsia, Thanks for helping with this problem  
I am still having problems with playframework 2.5.x, do you have any good book that can help me properly understand the framework?

Comment: @Alex Irabor I'd recommend you to take a look at the [specification](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Home) IMO - practice is the best way to learn something, I don't believe in books for programmers.

Comment: do you know how to setup play-mailer, I am having issues using it ?

Comment: @AlexIrabor I provided the answer to your question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51248686/6860682

Comment: My file shows up but instantly disappears. I save it in /tmp/picture

Comment: Using ref.renameTo  fixes my bug